# Error in Visual Studio: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, controller

This is homework, an ASP.NET MVC app in Visual Studio using C#.  When I run it, the error says, "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'," referring to the line:  Manufacturer = collection["Manufacturer"], Gears = collection["Gears"], Frame = collection["Frame"] and there's a squiggly line under Gears = collection["Gears"].

```
using MvcApplication3.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication3.Controllers
{
    public class BikeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Bike/

        List<Bike> bikes;


        public BikeController()
        {
            if (bikes == null)
            {
                bikes = new List<Bike> {
                new Bike(),
                new Bike { Manufacturer = "Nishiki", Gears = 5, Frame = "Road" }
            };
            }
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(this.bikes);
        }

        private ActionResult View(Func<object> func)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        //
        // GET: /Bike/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var currentBikes = bikes[id];
            return View(currentBikes);

        }

        //
        // GET: /Bike/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Bike/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
        {   
            Bike b = new Bike
            { 
                Manufacturer = collection["Manufacturer"], Gears = collection["Gears"], Frame = collection["Frame"]
            };
            bikes.Add(b);
            try
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Bike/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            return View(bikes.Where(b => b.BikeID == id).First());
        }

        //
        // POST: /Bike/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add update logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Bike/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Bike/Delete/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add delete logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        public int bike { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you _you_ think the error means?

Comment: I think it meant that it was rejecting the data type for Gears, which is an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly convert string to int.

Try following line

```
  Manufacturer = collection["Manufacturer"], Gears = int.Parse(collection["Gears"]), Frame = collection["Frame"]
```

Comment: That worked.  Thanks.  I didn't say that Gears was an int in the first place.  Does it go by what the first element is in the list?

Comment: No, it is not related to ordering, but datatype.

Comment: Yes, but why did it think Gears was a string?

Comment: Because `collection` seems to be dictionary of type `Dictionary<String,string>`.